# Updating UI elements inside an Async method doesn't work

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin14

Hello I have an async method called by a normal method which is addClickListener for a button anyway.

I wanted to update the ProgressBar inside the async method.

I already defined the progressBar and added it to the view.

```
@Async("DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor")
    private void runBulk(UI ui) {

        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedMigrationDataTest.size(); i++) {
           //Somecode 
     
            ui.access(() -> {
                progressBar.setValue(progressValue);
                progressBar.setVisible(true);
                ui.push();
            });

        }
    }
```

I do not see any changes happening inside the aysnc method. I can see only changes happening outside this method.

I tried to getting a new UI and passing UI from normal method.

I tried calling and not calling ui.push()

I am working Vaadin 14.9.5 and Sping-boot 2.7.7.

**Note**: this code used to work when I was calling this method using SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor without @Async of course.
I decided to use @Async for security context injection.

Comment: Have you remembered to enable push by adding `@Push` annotation to right place?

Comment: @TatuLund I actually didn't know about it. Thanks this solved my issue.